# How to make latest PostgreSQL version upgrade the default version in Ubuntu Focal Fossa

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Beforehand, I will admit that I am quite frustrated after attempting to upgrade my version of PostgreSQL-12 to PostgreSQL-16 in my virtual machine (Windows Subsystem for Linux2 Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Focal Fossa).  So please forgive my frustration.  It's not personal. Nonetheless, like Rich from ReviewTechUSA say, "Let's get into it."

After conducting further research, it seems that Ubuntu handles subsequent upgrading of a PostgreSQL version by keeping both the original and upgraded versions.  I discovered this after running the command *sudo service PostgreSQL start* resulting in the following output:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server                                                                        [ OK ]
 * Starting PostgreSQL 16 database server                                                                        [ OK ]
➜  ~ sudo service postgresql status
12/main (port 5432): online
16/main (port 5433): online
➜  ~
```

I now understand and respect why Ubuntu maintains both versions after an upgrade.  However, I need version 16 to be the default such that all psql and pg commands defer to version 16 instead of 12.  For example, I need the command line tools *pg_dump* and *pg_restore* to use the features associated with version 16 and not version 12. Moreover, the *psql* command should start a session in version 16 and not in version 12. Please help me to achieve this.  Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

FYI - Currently, the command *pg_restore --version* points to PostgreSQL-12:

```
➜  ~ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-1.pgdg20.04+1)
➜  ~
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to edit the `/etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/postgresql.conf` files and swap the ports where `5432` is for the 16 version and `5433` is for the 12 version. Then restart the servers. You could also read the blog posts I wrote about this [Install](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/06/29/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-1/) and [Commands](https://aklaver.org/wordpress/2023/07/01/postgres-debian-ubuntu-packagingpart-2/).

Comment: If you only want to run PostgreSQL 16 and don't need PostgreSQL 12, then just uninstall the latter. Dump the databases first in case something happens. In the future, instead of upgrading, dump the databases, uninstall the current release, install the new release, and then import the databases.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this resolved the issue

Comment: @NasirRiley perhaps I will uninstall version 12 in the future.  For now I will keep both version 12 and 16.